# Filter users by mobilePhone or businessPhones in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to filter users by phone? I'm trying to find contacts in the global address list by their phone numbers.

I've tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mobilePhone eq '+1234567890'` but I get the following error: 
`"code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
"message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'mobilePhone' of resource 'User'."`

also businessPhones/any does not seem to work.
However, the above query works fine in personal contacts but then I would have to manually sync the global address list to my personal contacts which is not desirable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's almost 4 years since the question being asked, as I'm also looking at the same question today, just going to leave the answer here for future wanderer.

According to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries, `mobilePhone` and `businessPhones` is consider an advanced queries, in order to query it, you need to have `$count=true` in the query string, and `ConsistencyLevel: eventual` in the header. And you might need to escape the `+` into `%2B`.

Microsoft announced this capability in 2020 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-advanced-queries-for-directory-objects-are-now-generally-available/.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=businessPhones/any(p:p le 'a') or mobilePhone ne null&$count=true
```

with headers `ConsistencyLevel: eventual` to get users with at least one businessPhone or a mobile.

the `le 'a'` compares the businessPhone string with the letter `a`, and since it's after `+(123456789` in the alphabet, it'll return true for everything that's non empty

Answer (score 1):

For copypasting:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(mobilePhone,'%2B73334442211')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mobilePhone,mail
```

Ensure `ConsistencyLevel: eventual` header

Test your tenant with https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/graph-explorer (**sign in** first)

Thanks to @aron-atilla-hegedus and @stephen-saw

Answer (score -1):

The various phone properties are supported in `$filter`.

I would recommending visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion (and voting up others).